# Spring-AMQP - routing based on message headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

As per the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven

We can have different handlers for messages based on it's converted class type like:

```
@RabbitListener(id="multi", queues = "someQueue")
@SendTo("my.reply.queue")
public class MultiListenerBean {

    @RabbitHandler
    public String thing2(Thing2 thing2) {
        ...
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public String cat(Cat cat) {
        ...
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public String hat(@Header("amqp_receivedRoutingKey") String rk, @Payload Hat hat) {
        ...
    }

    @RabbitHandler(isDefault = true)
    public String defaultMethod(Object object) {
        ...
    }

}
```

This I believe won't be great in performance since it has to do a trial and error to cast the incoming payload.

Instead, how to filter based on a condition say a header value? If header['operation']="order" then cast the message payload to Order class.

Answer (score 0):

> This I believe won't be great in performance since it has to do a trial and error to cast the incoming payload.

Usually, type information is conveyed in headers and the `MessageConverter` uses that information to create the payload - there is no "trial and error".

If you don't use one of the supplied converters, you can create your own, based on `header['operation']`.

Comment: Gary, when we use jackson2JsonMessageConverter, and use different class types in Multi-Method listener, how does the converter determine the destination type?

Comment: See the `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` used by the converter; the type information is conveyed in headers; either a FQCN or a token that is mapped from/to a class.